# Install current windows system once replaced by Ubuntu

Tags: windows, virtualbox, kubuntu

I would like to know if it is technically possible to virtualize 
a windows 8 operating system on a machine. 
Then completely replace windows by Ubuntu on the same machine
And install the virtualized window 8 on the Ubuntu virtualBox
Do you think windows will be functional
Or does it need to retrieve the licence key ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, as the new install will not have the license key automatically available.

It used to be possible to convert an existing hardware based windows installation to a VMware¹ or VirtualBox VM, but Windows licensing seems to have gotten more restrictive over time (with hardware change tests). [This](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows) explains how to do things, but it remarks it should work for Win2K, Vista and Windows 7, and doesn't mention Windows 8 at all.

I would not do a complete replacement, but minimize the Windows 8 install. Install Ubuntu in the rest, then try and convert the Windows 8 install to a virtual machine while Ubuntu is running. If that works with licenses et all you are home free. If the latter doesn't succeed, install Windows 8 and try to reuse your license on the VM. Only when the VM works you should reclaim the raw disc space Windows 8 is taking.

¹ <sub>VMware used to have a mode where you run the VM while the raw HD is used. This had some restrictions but worked. I haven't used that however for over 10</sub> years.

Comment: Alternatively  do you think it is also possible to do a disk recovery image from windows on a boot USB and a virtualization, then replace windows by linux, try the VirtualBox installation with the virtual windows and if it doesn't work replace linux by windows with the recovery image? (In that case do you think windows will be back working?)
As I need windows only for few dependant softwares but I'm mainly working on Linux for all the rest. (perhaps I could use Wine. Do you recommend any other softwares than Wine to do the same)Thanks.

Comment: I have been working with VMware since 1999, switched to VirtualBox in 2008, I never had the need for using Wine. You can do a full backup of your HDD and restore, but I doubt it will fit on a USB. I would invest in an external HHD drive big enough to do that kind of thing. That is a whole new question in its own right.